# Given employees and departments tables find missing department id

Tags: mysql

I am given a table of employees and a table of departments. The table "Employees" has missing manager id and missing department id. The structure of tables is in the fiddle below. 
I am asked to find those missing department ids. From what I see,  one manager can work with several departments.
There are no further assumptions. This is what I have tried. But  it is not correct. Is it possible to solve without having more information about the problem?
I assume also no hardcoding of missing data.

```
select 
e.name as emp_name,
d.name as dep_name,
Dep_id, Manager_id, 
Salary
from Employees as e 
left join departments as d
on d.id=e.dep_id
order by Salary  desc;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8fa05

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `departments` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `departments` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
  ('1', 'Finance'),
  ('2', 'Operations'),
  ('3', 'Deployment');
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200),
  `Dep_id` int(6) unsigned ,
  `Manager_id` int(6) unsigned,
  `Salary` int ,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `employees` (`id`, `name`, `Dep_id`, `Manager_id`, `Salary`) VALUES
  ('1', 'John Smith',1,NULL,2000 ),
  ('2', 'Jack Smith',NULL,1, 1500),
  ('3', 'Becky Smith',1,2,2000),
  ('4', 'Rebecca Smith',2,2,700),
  ('5', 'Sonny Smith',3,1,3000);
```

Comment: If you're looking for `Employees` that have missing `departments_id` just do `SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Dep_id IS NULL`

Comment: Thanks. But that is precisely what i was trying with left join. I need to find the dep_id for each employee. I am not entirely sure that it  is possible though. May be some sort of cartesian would help. I need a hint on how to proceed.

Comment: @SAMIR - not sure about that manager_id is always present (I think) so employee must belong to one of the departments manager manages. OP I suspect wants a list of departments manager manages.

Comment: What's your expected result given your sample data.

Comment: @P.Salmon    For the first row of the employees table the manager_id is missing

Comment: @P.Salmon  the expected result is to find all missing dep_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I could think of is getting `dep_id` and `manager_id` from other employees who have the same not `null` `manager_id` and `dep_id` respectively.
This does not give a unique solution if as you say: *one manager can work with several departments*, this is why I used aggregation to pick one of them:

```
select 
  e.id, e.name, 
  max(coalesce(e.dep_id, ee.dep_id)) dep_id, 
  max(coalesce(e.manager_id, ee.manager_id)) manager_id, 
  e.salary
from employees e 
left join employees ee on ee.dep_id = e.dep_id or ee.manager_id = e.manager_id
group by e.id, e.name, e.salary
order by e.id
```

If the table is large maybe it would be more efficient to split the query in 2 parts (to avoid joins and aggregation for all the rows) and then use `UNION ALL` for the final results:

```
select e.* from employees e 
where e.dep_id is not null and e.manager_id is not null
union all
select 
  e.id, e.name, 
  max(coalesce(e.dep_id, ee.dep_id)) dep_id, 
  max(coalesce(e.manager_id, ee.manager_id)) manager_id, 
  e.salary
from employees e 
left join employees ee on ee.dep_id = e.dep_id or ee.manager_id = e.manager_id
where e.dep_id is null or e.manager_id is null
group by e.id, e.name, e.salary
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e60b67509b0a8a43ec723851b3947ef3).
Results:

```
id | name          | dep_id | manager_id | salary
-: | :------------ | -----: | ---------: | -----:
 1 | John Smith    |      1 |          2 |   2000
 2 | Jack Smith    |      3 |          1 |   1500
 3 | Becky Smith   |      1 |          2 |   2000
 4 | Rebecca Smith |      2 |          2 |    700
 5 | Sonny Smith   |      3 |          1 |   3000
```

So `'John Smith'` gets `manager_id = 2` because `'Becky Smith'` is in the same department and has this `manager_id`.
Also `'Jack Smith'` gets `dep_id = 3` because `'Sonny Smith'` has the same manager with that `dep_id`.

Comment: Is there another way to get his dep_id?

Comment: Just to add some clarity.  Jack Smith need not have the same dep_id as Sonny Smith as a consequence of having same manager. On the contrary, Becky and Rebecca Smiths get the same manager_id but different dep_ids.
Now, suppose, Jack Smith gets  dep_id=1. This means that one dep_id may be related to several manager_ids  (dep_id=1 is assigned to managers 1 and 2). This can neither  be traced from the data  nor assumed. But the marked answer is as close as it gets to solving the problem without assuming more than one thing

Comment: If i knew this coalesce function probably i could have solved it on my own.